# @ComponentScan is not applied - all Java packages are scanned

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app with several dependencies:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.test.adapter",
                "com.dependency.commons.framework.util"}
)
```

But during startup I see that call packages from dependency jar are applied and I get conflicts.
Do you know how I can apply only Java package: `"com.dependency.commons.framework.util"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution A

Use the attribute `excludeFilters` of `@ComponentScan`.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.adapter",
                "com.dependency.commons.framework.util" },
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.example.ignore.packages.*"))
```

### Solution B

As your title of the question is

> @ComponentScan is not applied - all Java packages are scanned

Probably your launcher class that has the `@SpringBootApplication` is on a upper level of a package. Spring will automatically scan all the classes that are on that level of where this class is placed and all nested subpackages.

See the following structure as an example

[image]

What you can do here to avoid that is to move the launcher class inside a specific package outside of the root package

[image]